# Regular expression for substitute a string with another

Tags: regex

I have this two lines of text, that I want to manipulate using Regular Expression and substitute:

```
Obj.FieldNameA = Reader.GetEnumFromInt32<ClassName>(QueryGenerator,nameof(Obj.));
Obj.FieldNameB=Reader.GetTrimmedStringOrNull(QueryGenerator,nameof(Obj.));
```

Attached on the first `Obj.` there is a Field name, so in this case they are `FieldNameA`,`FieldNameB`

I want to attach these values to the second `Obj.` found on the same line, so the text should become:

```
Obj.FieldNameA = Reader.GetEnumFromInt32<ClassName>(QueryGenerator,nameof(Obj.FieldNameA));
Obj.FieldNameB=Reader.GetTrimmedStringOrNull(QueryGenerator,nameof(Obj.FieldNameB));
```

I have tested this very simple (and wrong) regex:
`Obj\.(\w*).*\n`

With substituition as `$1`

But I don't know how to use substitution...

[Sample code here](https://regex101.com/r/VUEOP6/1)

Some Notes:
After `FieldNameA` there is always an equal sign that could be preceded or followed by a space.
Before the second `Obj.` there could be any character, including `<` `(` etc...

Could this be achieved?

Comment: Try `(Obj\.(\w+).*\(Obj\.)\)` => `$1$2)`. Or even add `^` to the start of the regex  to match at the start of a line/string. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/h57iTV/1)

Comment: Yes, thaks Wiktor, that seems right!

Comment: See my explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find**: `(Obj\.(\w+).*\(Obj\.)\)` 
**Replace**: `$1$2)`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h57iTV/1).

You may also add `^` to the start of the regex to match only at the start of a line/string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(Obj\.(\w+).*\(Obj\.)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement):

  - `Obj\.` - `Obj.` text
  - `(\w+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): 1 or more word chars
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible  (you may use `.*?` to only match the *second* `Obj.` on a line, your current input only has two with the second one closer to the end of a line, so `.*` will work better)
  - `\(Obj\.` - `(Obj.` text
- `\)` - a `)` char.